# How to retrieve the date using retrofit in this json file?

Tags: android, retrofit

I dont know how to retrieve the date in this json file , normally the date change everytime ,it depends to the request , here is my json file , and here is an example of a request https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2018-01-01&end_at=2018-09-01&base=USD&symbols=ILS

please could someone suggest me how to retrieve the data in this case

```
{
    "rates": {
        "2018-05-04": {
            "ILS": 3.6211880692
        },
        "2018-08-27": {
            "ILS": 3.6345740566
        },
        "2018-06-08": {
            "ILS": 3.5740173558
        },
        "2018-08-22": {
            "ILS": 3.6355027548
        },
}
```

and this is my model

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Rates {
    @SerializedName("CAD")
    @Expose
    private String cad;
    @SerializedName("JPY")
    @Expose
    private String jpy;
    @SerializedName("EUR")
    @Expose
    private String eur;

    @SerializedName("AUD")
    @Expose
    private String aud;

    @SerializedName("PHP")
    @Expose
    private String php;

    @SerializedName("ZAR")
    @Expose
    private String zar;

    public String getCad() {
        return cad;
    }

    public String getJpy() {
        return jpy;
    }

    public String getEur() {
        return eur;
    }

    public String getAud() {
        return aud;
    }

    public String getPhp() {
        return php;
    }

    public String getZar() {
        return zar;
    }
}



import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class JsonObject implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("rates")
    @Expose
    private Rates rates;

    public Rates getRates() {
        return rates;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that your JSON is actually an object having `Map<String, Rates>`, so something like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Response {
    private Map<String, Rates> rates;
}
```

So getting rate for some day - say "2018-08-22" - would go like:

```
response.get("2018-08-22").getIls(); // returns 3.6355027548
```

When deserializing to a map you do not need to know the keys (so dates here). That is the point of map: there can be any key pointing to some value. So when Retrofit (or actually I think there is a GsonConverter so Gson) deserializes this JSON it adds ANY key - like "2018-08-22" - having value to the map.

In other words when your JSON is deserialized to a map that map would have `keySet()`

> "2018-05-04",
> "2018-08-27",
> "2018-06-08",
> "2018-08-22"

and this set of keys would tell you for which dates there are rates.

**NOTE**: your `Rates` dos not currently have currency **ILS**. Also Map<String, Rates> could be Map<Date, Rates> but I have used String instead of Date to keep the example more simple (no date formats or so).

Comment: the problem in the date normally it changes everytime , I dont have it

Comment: Then your option is: `map.keySet()`